# Padding between icon and text in submenu (Android)

Tags: android, menu

I have a such menu

```
<menu>
<item
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
    android:title="@string/more"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/follow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_follow"
            android:title="@string/follow"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:title="@string/share"
            />
```

... (and more same items)

How can I reduce space (padding) between icon and text in submenu?

http://scydiamond.ucoz.ru/_ph/33/2/260565245.png?1437410291

Comment: what is the size of your icon??
can you verify that

Comment: Icon size is for hdpi 24*24 and so on for other dpi.

Comment: There are no extra empty space in icons

Comment: did you find an answer to this yet ? I am fighting the same problem and don't have a solution yet. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this doesn't answer directly, but I couldn't add a comment because of low rep.

Instead of reducing the spacing, I would suggest you trust the aesthetics of the system, and increase the icon resource size.Keep very low padding for the drawables.

I use this for generating all my icons

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=0&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example

Keep size at 24dip and padding at 0dip. Download the zip and merge with the `/res/` directory. :)